# When I'm trying to refresh my page of react application for '/login' it's showing error Cannot GET /login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom, vercel

When I refreshing the page for the link /login I'm getting error Cannot GET /login. I have hosted the react app on Vercel. Below is the screenshot attached.
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf8Qr.jpg)

My index.js file code is:

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')

connectToMongo();

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.json()) // this middleware is used if you want to send request through body req.body
app.use(cors());

// available routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/notes', require('./routes/notes'));


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  
  const path = require('path')

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')))
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`iNotebook backend app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

My vercel.json file code is:

```
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"

        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/.*",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to refresh the page but it showing error. However, it was supposed to show login page.

Comment: Move the static middleware out of your `GET /` handler

Comment: change your "dest" from "/" to "dest" : "index.js'

Comment: @Phil How? Can u please elaborate..

Answer (score -1):

Change your vercel.json file :

```
{
"builds": [
    {
        "src": "index.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"

    }
],
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/.*",
        "dest": "index.js"
    }
]
```

}

change dest from "/" into "index.js"

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: did you change the build source to index.js ?

Comment: Got solution from https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing